Google colab edit files with long lines
I have a txt file with a very long line on Google colab. When I try to edit it by double clicking the file in the left panel, first there is no line-wrapping on this long line in the editor, and second when I left click on the editor to start editing, the view becomes all messed up (because of this long line) and I can’t edit the file anymore. I need to change the page layout to be able to edit my file again.
Anyone else encountering the same bug? Any workaround? If not, is it possible to load and edit a file directly in a cell, or edit in another editor than the default one?
